# compiling old glibc on arm fails with undefined references in nis and nss

Tags: compiling, glibc, dynamic-linking, cross-compilation, arch-arm

It seems to have become a bit complex, so first some background:

I need to compile self-contained programs that run on arm systems with `glibc` versions typically between 2.13 and 2.17.

When trying to run these programs, I often get an error like this:

```
dlopen: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.26' not found (required by /tmp/_MEImvaIVL/libpython3.8.so.1.0)
```

(In this case I'm using a program with embedded python interpreter, packaged with `PyInstaller`)

I have a working workflow to build the `python` used in that case from source, and use that `python` to build the final package, so I figured if I just build it under the right `glibc` version I'm good to go.

I'm using build containers (first `docker`, now `buildah` (since it gives me much more flexibility to interact with my build containers)), based on `debian:stretch-arm32v7`.

After significant *trial & horror*, `glibc` seems to compile quite well initially, but now I'm stuck at:

```
gcc -no-pie -shared -static-libgcc -Wl,-O1  -Wl,-z,defs -Wl,-dynamic-linker=/opt/glibc-2.17/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3  -B/buildroot/build/csu/  -Wl,--version-script=/buildroot/build/libnss_db.map -Wl,-soname=libnss_db.so.2 -Wl,-z,combreloc -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--hash-style=both  -L/buildroot/build -L/buildroot/build/math -L/buildroot/build/elf -L/buildroot/build/dlfcn -L/buildroot/build/nss -L/buildroot/build/nis -L/buildroot/build/rt -L/buildroot/build/resolv -L/buildroot/build/crypt -L/buildroot/build/nptl -Wl,-rpath-link=/buildroot/build:/buildroot/build/math:/buildroot/build/elf:/buildroot/build/dlfcn:/buildroot/build/nss:/buildroot/build/nis:/buildroot/build/rt:/buildroot/build/resolv:/buildroot/build/crypt:/buildroot/build/nptl -o /buildroot/build/nss/libnss_db.so -T /buildroot/build/shlib.lds /buildroot/build/csu/abi-note.o -Wl,--whole-archive /buildroot/build/nss/libnss_db_pic.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive /buildroot/build/elf/interp.os /buildroot/build/linkobj/libc.so /buildroot/build/libc_nonshared.a /buildroot/build/nss/libnss_files.so
/buildroot/build/nss/libnss_db_pic.a(db-proto.os): In function `_nss_db_getprotoent_r':
db-proto.c:(.text+0x15c): undefined reference to `_nss_files_parse_protoent'
/buildroot/build/nss/libnss_db_pic.a(db-proto.os): In function `_nss_db_getprotobyname_r':
db-proto.c:(.text+0x268): undefined reference to `_nss_files_parse_protoent'

... (more failing functions) ...

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
../Makerules:446: recipe for target '/buildroot/build/nss/libnss_db.so' failed
make[2]: *** [/buildroot/build/nss/libnss_db.so] Error 1
```

If I enter the container and copy&paste above `gcc` command, I can immediately reproduce this error. Now if I add the flags `-L/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf` (which contains the host's `libnss_files.so` and the functions the linker can't find, and execute the command again, I get the same error, but if I also add `-lnss_files` (unsurprisingly?) it works. But this will be the case for many more files, so there must be a deeper lying problem?

What surprises me is the flag `-Wl,-dynamic-linker=/opt/glibc-2.17/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3` in above command. While that indeed is the final target (`--prefix=/opt/glibc-2.17`), it is still empty since `glibc` is still being built.

Is somehow `glibc` not bootstrapping correctly?

Any ideas?

TIA!

Comment: Are you doing a full gcc/glibc bootstrap, or just glibc?

Comment: @StephenKitt for now I focused on `glibc`, but it it turns out I run into problems related to `gcc` (I'm now just using the one from `debiab:stretch-arm32v7`), I might need to include it as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to bootstrap the GCC/glibc pair completely — GCC embeds some knowledge of the C library it was built with.

I suspect a simpler solution in your case is to use older images with older versions of glibc; for example, `debian:wheezy` is available for ARMv7 and uses glibc 2.13.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try that first and report back...

Comment: Great, it worked! It was not completely trivial, since *wheezy* is so old it is hidden in the debian archives, and a few deps for python (notably ` openssl`) where difficult, mainly because `python`  tells you version 1.0.2 is sufficient, but it is not. So needed to install that from source. But Now I have nice build containers based on `glibc-2.13-armhf`